# How to pass nested parameter inside formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, form-data

I have a scenario where I have to save a file (images) first the parent and then the child table, one to many relation. And I am passing a parameter in formdata. However, I am not able to pass a nested parameter inside formdata.

I am using Angular to pass the data.
My code below:

```js
const formData = new FormData();

if (product.nestedImage.length > 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < product.nestedImage.length; i++) {
    formData.append(`image${i + 1 }`, product.nestedImage[I])
  }
}
for(let key in product) {
  if (key !== 'nestedImage') {
    formData.append(key, product[key]);
  } 
} 
return this.http.post(this.createImagesDetails, formData,  { observe:'response'})
```

Below image is my parameter while hitting the API [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCjep.png)

However, I want image1 to be nested

```
nestedFiles.image1: value
```

I am using nodejs to save the data in the table.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to send multiple images?  `formData.append("image", img1);` and `formData.append("image", img2);`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append for more info about multiple values with the same name.

Comment: yeah I want to pass multiple images but not in same object, I want to pass in nested object.
i.e 
object.image1: value ===> First one
object.nestedObject.nestedImage: value === > nested one

I have to pass like that.

Comment: I dont think FormData supports nested objects directly.  Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566331/formdata-append-nested-object

Comment: So is there any alternative solution? I am only aware about the Formdata.